# How to get HTML element by XPATH in Selenium, when XPATH is always changing (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using Python and Selenium to locate and click an element on a web page.

Here is my code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_panel_609"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/li/div'))).click()
```

It works, but the problem is that the table panel number changes every time I refresh the page.

```
[@id="tab_panel_???"]
```

Is there a way to find elements by XPATH while accounting for the changing value?